# CrudRepository - query method name that filters objects based on parameter properties of member List variable

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm using `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`. I have a repository and some nested entities that look like this.

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, Integer> {
    //Want to put something here like
    //Country country = findCountryWhereSomeCompanyHasId(String id)
}

@Entity
public class Country{
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Company> companies;

    //Get, set and id
}


@Entity
public class Company{
    private String uniqueInternationalOrgNr;

    //Get, set and id
}
```

Suppose I have some `uniqueInternationalOrgNr`, and I want to find which country this company belongs to. I want to type in a method name in the `CrudRepository` interface so that Spring automatically implements the method for me. What would this method name be? On first glance, through the IntelliJ autocompletion feature, it might seem as if I can't make queries based on the properties of a `List<>` parameter.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation of JPQL? Especially the part about joins? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: Is JPQL directly relevant here? I'm trying to figure out whether there is some method name that Spring will recognize, and then generate a method implementation for me. Not sure if it was clear enough in the original post. I have made an edit.

Comment: For all but the simplest queries (such as findByName), you'd better choose the best name you want for your method, and annotate the method with `Query`. When you know JPQL (which you should), this not only leads to better and more maintainable code, but is also faster because you don't have to find out what the magical method name should be.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring you can use nested properties.
[Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, Integer> {
    Country findByCompaniesUniqueInternationalOrgNr(String id);
}
```

When you have a many-to-many relation you probably need to change the return type to `List<Country>`.